# Adding JQuery Reference breaks tags input

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using a template that comes with a nice Tags Input, but I now want to be able to count the number of words and limit the number of words based on certain criteria, however, the only way I've found to do this is by using keyup of the specific textboxfor, but to do this I need to reference to JQuery, but then it breaks my tags input. Below is what I currently have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmploymentSkills, new { @id = "tags", @class = "form-control tagsinput", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Add skill and press enter", data_role = "tagsinput" })

<script src="~/SmartAdmin/scripts/plugin/bootstrap-tags/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way I can do this with out referencing to JQuery, or able to reference to it and not break my tags input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution to this. As mentioned above, the .keyup or .keydown didnt work, so I landed up using  .change. This is the function I used, also counting the number of words and limiting them:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $(".tagsinput").change(function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val().replace(" ", "");
        var words = value.split(",");

        if (words.length > '@Model.TagsAllowed') {
            alert("You are not allowed more than '@Model.TagsAllowed' tags!");

            var lastword = value.split(",").pop();
            value = value.replace(',' + lastword, '');
            $(this).val(value);
            $('.tagsinput').val() = value.substring(0, value.length - lastword.length);
        }
    });
})
```

Hope this helps anyone else somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something specific with `data_role`attribute? As long as i remember you should put all attributes in @ if using XPath. Try replacing `data_role = 'tagsinput'` to `@data-role = 'tagsinput'`. Maybe that is causing the issue.

Comment: Gave it a go but still have the issue. Just to confirm, the tags work, but the moment I add a reference to a JQuery file, then the tags break(i.e. it now shows as C#,SQL,MVC instead of the tags).

Comment: Can you please post the code where you reference jQuery?

Comment: Thats where the problem comes in. This view is not referencing jQuery. The moment I do, my tags break. I want to add the reference so that I can make use of the keyup function - However with out the reference, the keyup function doesnt work. Am I missing the point ?